# Как быть с роутами, куда копать (новичок)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel7

Laravel7. Изменил стартовую страницу на auth.login При логине меня редиректит в /home. Но если я введу domain.com, то я опять попадаю на логин форму и могу по новой ввести данные, но если в адресной строке ввести domain.com/home то меня туда пускает. Если я авторизованный укажу domain.com/login, то меня редиректит в /home т.к. я уже авторизован. Подскажите где смотреть?

Comment: пройдите официальные и прекрасные курсы по laravel. Бесплатные. Есть даже русские субтитры. н

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю никто не знает как именно вы переназначали стартовую страницу на auth.login потому если бы вы более подробно описали, что вы сделали вам бы побыстрее ответили. Я могу предположить что вы просто вывели на главной

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

Вместо того чтобы скажем закрыть главную через middleware auth. 
При этом все что вы сделали это вывели "вид" - форму авторизации.  Лучшим способом было бы сделать скажем так:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

а чтобы не редиректило на /home указали бы в App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider; изменить путь для

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

И да вы не поверите но все это есть в документации

Comment: Сейчас курю документацию. Вы правы, я сделал именно так `код`     return view('auth.login');`код` Но проблема в том, что при логине меня редиректит туда, куда надо. Но вот если я залогиненный введу domain.com/login, то меня редиректит в HOME т.к. я уже авторизован, а вот если я введу domain.com он мне предлагает ввести логин и пароль (которые уже введены).Буду делать в таком духе и разбираться, только учусь    Route::get('/', function() {
  if (Auth::check()) {
     return redirect()->route('news');
  }
  else {
    return view('welcome');
  }
}